# Why from is submitted multiple time if click save button quickly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view which is a bootstrap pop up. Every thing is working fine but if i click on a button quickly until pop gone the form and record submitted multiple  times. There is also remote validation on it and it works fine. But for the first time, form submitted multiple times as multiple clicks. Why?

Comment: It's a normal behavior. If you want to skip it just add click handler for the button and disable the submit button before the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick double-click on a button or link can have unintended consequences, such as a form being submitted twice or the same process running in parallel to itself and encountering race conditions. To stop this unintended behavior, you can write simple java script code to disable the button or a flag to maintain that form is already submitted or not. For ex :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isFormSubmitted(form) // Submit button clicked
  {
    form.submitButton.disabled = true;
    return true;
  }

  var isSubmitted = false;
  function isFormSubmitted(form) // global variable
  {
    if (!isSubmitted) {
        isSubmitted = true;
        return false; 
    }

    return true;
  }

</script>
```